# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %' issue when using jsonp with angular5

Tags: angular5

I am new to angular5 and I trying to call a api using 'jsonp' property.

```
this.http.jsonp('http://localhost/angular5/lesson2.pdf?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK').subscribe(res=>{
     console.log(res);
   })
```

in the above code I am using 'HttpClinetJsonpModule' for calling the api.But it returns following error.
[image]
can anyone please help me to solve this issue.I already spend a few hous in it.

Comment: You are missing the second parameter to the `jsonp(...)` method. I think it will be `'callback'` in your case. https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#jsonp

Comment: Also, please don't ask the same question twice. If you have more details, update your previous question instead of asking another. You should delete the other question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213580/failed-to-get-response-when-using-jsonp-with-angular-5